# Scanner not scanning until two outputs?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

```
System.out.print("This program computes the average and variance of all numbers entered. ");

    boolean finished = false;
    int total = 0;

    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    double average = inputScanner.nextDouble();
    double variance = inputScanner.nextDouble();

    while (!finished)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number (or type 'exit'): ");

        if (inputScanner.hasNextDouble())
        {

            total++;
            System.out.println(total);
            double currentNum = inputScanner.nextDouble();
            average = (average) + (currentNum - average) / total;
            double prevAverage = ((average * total) - currentNum) / (total - 1);
            variance = ((variance * (total - 1)) + (currentNum - prevAverage) 
                                                            * (currentNum - average)) / total;

            System.out.println("So far the average is: " + average 
                                            + "\nAnd the variance so far is: " + variance );

        }
        else if (inputScanner.hasNext("exit"))
        {
            finished = true;
            System.out.println("Thanks for using this program.");
            inputScanner.close();
```

Not sure why I have to put two input before it asks me to put in a number? Also the variance formula comes out as NaN and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

```
double var1 = (variance * (total - 1));
            double var2 = (currentNum - prevAverage) * (currentNum -         average);  
            variance = (var1 + var2) / total;
```

This is my calculation for the variance now. How do I fix it? If I input '1' var2 is NaN, and if I input 2 var1 is Nan.

Comment: I fixed the whole input scanner thing, now I'm just wondering how to get the variance working?

Comment: Java casts every intermediate numeric result to `int` if you don't explicitly state otherwise. I suggest you split your calculation into parts, assigning each part to a separate `double` variable, and then combining the parts.

Answer (score 0):

You call inputScanner.nextDouble() twice before entering the loop.
This requires two values before it can continue.

I suggest you change it to

```
double variance = 0.0;
```

Comment: I fixed the whole input scanner thing, now I'm just wondering how to get the variance working?

Comment: Well, did you write the code or just copy it? Did you try to debug it? Do you know [how to calculate a variance](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html)?

Comment: I wrote it myself, haven't debugged I'll try to do that, and no we were just given the formula for it

Comment: I suggest you try it with some simple values, calculate it by hand and find where it goes wrong

Comment: The issue you asked about is solved, why don't you mark a solution as solved and then ask again with the other issue you have?

Answer (score 0):

You have to type two input before "Enter a number (or type 'exit'): " statement as Before the line below:
      double currentNum = inputScanner.nextDouble();

you are accepting two double values from user using below lines:
      double average = inputScanner.nextDouble();
      double variance = inputScanner.nextDouble();

remove above two lines and only declare/initialize the variable will resolve your problem.

You are getting NaN in variance as before the below formula
 you are doing total++ inside loop, which will evaluate to value 1
so in next line total-1 will become 0, and devide anything by zoro will be NaN

double prevAverage = ((average * total) - currentNum) / (total - 1); // will be NaN

Comment: I fixed the whole input scanner thing, now I'm just wondering how to get the variance working?

Answer (score 0):

By doing this before the loop:

```
double average = inputScanner.nextDouble();
double variance = inputScanner.nextDouble();
```

You are blocking until the user has entered two double values...

EDIT: variance calculation (I'm not checking it's semantics BTW)

```
double totalVar = variance * (double) (total - 1);
double currentNumMinusPreviousAvg = currentNum - prevAverage;
double currentNumMinusAvg = currentNum - average;    
variance = (totalVar + currentNumMinusPreviousAvg * currentNumMinusAvg) / total;
```

Something like this should avoid uninteded casts to `int` for intermediate expressions and with approriate variable names makes the calculation more readble too.

Comment: I fixed the whole input scanner thing, now I'm just wondering how to get the variance working?

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly querying the user, and you should only do it in the beginning of the loop, and store it in a variable to use it in the if-else statement. Since it can be a String, let's ask for a string, and parse it later to a double.

```java
boolean finished = false;
int total = 0;

Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
double average = inputScanner.nextDouble();
double variance = inputScanner.nextDouble();

while (!finished) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number (or type 'exit'): ");
    String input = inputScanner.nextLine();


    if( input.equals( "exit" ) ) {
        finished = true;
        System.out.println("Thanks for using this program.");
        inputScanner.close();
    }
    else {
        try {
            double nextDouble = Double.parseDouble( input );

            //If an exception is trown it won't get past here, so 
            //it won't count
            total++;
            System.out.println(total);

            double currentNum = nextDouble;
            average = (average) + (currentNum - average) / total;
            double prevAverage = ((average * total) - currentNum) / (total - 1);
            variance = ((variance * (total - 1)) + (currentNum - prevAverage) 
                    * (currentNum - average)) / total;

            System.out.println("So far the average is: " + average 
                    + "\nAnd the variance so far is: " + variance );
        }
        catch ( NumberFormatException ex ) {
            System.out.println( "The number is badly writen" );
            //It can throw NumberFormatException exception if the 
            //number is badly writen.
        }
    }

}
```

Also, if you intend to use decimal numbers with precision, I advice to use the `BigDecimal` class.

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)